# decode json based on the value of a field with Data.Aeson

Tags: haskell

How would you implement the FromJson of this Sum Type ?

```
data CommandRequest = CreateWorkspace {commandId :: UUID , workspaceId ::UUID }
                 | IntroduceIdea {commandId :: UUID , workspaceId ::UUID , ideaContent :: String}

instance ToJSON CommandRequest where
   toJSON (CreateWorkspace commandId workspaceId) = object [
          "commandId" .= commandId,
          "workspaceId" .= workspaceId,
          "commandName" .= pack "createWorkspace"]
   toJSON (IntroduceIdea commandId workspaceId ideaContent) = object [
             "commandId" .= commandId,
             "workspaceId" .= workspaceId,
             "commandName" .= pack "introduceIdea",
             "ideaContent" .= ideaContent
             ]

instance FromJSON CommandRequest  where ... ?
```

so based on the commandName field commandName, I would to be able to re-construct the commands.

Update : with the help of you guys, here is the result :

```
instance FromJSON CommandRequest  where

parseJSON (Object jsonObject) = do
         commandName <- jsonObject .: "commandName"
         case commandName of
              Just (String "createWorkspace") -> CreateWorkspace
                  <$> jsonObject .: "commandId"
                  <*> jsonObject .: "workspaceId"
              Just (String "introduceIdea") -> IntroduceIdea
                  <$> jsonObject .: "commandId"
                  <*> jsonObject .: "workspaceId"
                  <*> jsonObject .: "ideaContent"
              Just (String unknownCommandName) -> error $ "Command unknown : " ++ unpack unknownCommandName
              Nothing -> error $ "Command name not provided"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take a peek at the `commandName` with `(.:)` and decide what to do. So:

```
instance FromJSON CommandRequest  where
    parseJSON (Object o) = do
        commandName <- o .: "commandName"
        case commandName :: String of
            "createWorkspace" -> liftA2 CreateWorkspace (o .: "commandId") (o .: "workspaceId")
            "introduceIdea" -> liftA3 IntroduceIdea (o .: "commandId") (o .: "workspaceId") (o .: "ideaContent")
            _ -> typeMismatch "wrongo" (Object o)
    parseJSON v = typeMismatch "double wrongo" v
```